# Minimise the area of an origin-centred ellipse with the constraint that it most enclose a particular circle

Tags: calculus, optimization, conic-sections

If the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is to enclose the circle $x^2+y^2 = 2y$, what values of $a$ and $b$ minimise the area of the ellipse?

Comment: Try drawing the circle, then it will become quite apparent what the answer is that you need to prove.

Comment: This is a really intriguing question, and I want to see it answered! So please include your attempts and reasoning so it doesn’t get closed as a blatant solve-this-problem-for-me post.

Answer (score 7):

If the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is tangent to the circle $x^2+(y-1)^2=1$ we have that the discriminant of
$q(y) = a^2\left(1-\frac{y^2}{b^2}\right)+y^2-2y $ is zero, hence $a^4+b^2 = a^2 b^2$. Assuming $a,b>0$ the area enclosed by $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ is $\pi a b$, hence we want to solve the minimization problem
$$ \min_{a^4+b^2=a^2 b^2}\pi a b = \pi \sqrt{\min_{a^4=b^2(a^2-1)}a^2 b^2}=\pi\sqrt{\min_{a>1} \frac{a^6}{a^2-1}}.$$
The minimum area is $\frac{3\pi}{2}\sqrt{3}$ and it is is achieved by $a=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, $b=\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$:

[image]

The origin and the tangency points are the vertices of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the given unit circle.

Comment: Nice solution (+1). Can you arrive at the last conclusion without using the discriminant method? If so then that would be an even more direct solution.

Comment: @hypergeometric: actually I believe the opposite: to use discriminants here is faster than using derivatives or partial derivatives.

Comment: Amazing!! There’s so much elegance in this answer. The insight about the discriminant I particularly love—it’s both a tool to quickly arrive at the solution as well as a way of guaranteeing that the ellipse isn’t merely secant to the circle.

Comment: It would be interesting to see this method extended to problems in which the points of intersection did *not* share a common abscissa/ordinate. I’m sure there are easier ways in such cases, but I wonder if one could use a change of coordinate systems in which the quadratic is in the variable representing the dimension parallel to the line through the points of intersection. Of course, this would also alter the equations of the loci, in which case one might not be able to isolate a single variable via elimination.

Comment: I meant using the equilateral triangle as the starting point, i.e. a purely geometrical approach, instead of discriminant. No derivatives or partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

Calling

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1=0\\
g(x,y) = x^2+y^2-2y=0
$$

at the tangency points we have

$$
\nabla f(x,y) = \lambda \nabla g(x,y)
$$

or

$$
\frac{2x}{a^2}=\lambda 2x\\
\frac{2y}{b^2}=\lambda(2y-2)
$$

so we obtain

$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{a^2}\Rightarrow \frac{y}{b^2}=\frac{1}{a^2}(y-1)\Rightarrow y = \frac{b^2}{b^2-a^2}
$$

etc.

NOTE

This can be used to solve the minimization problem. Calling $ S = \pi a b$ the area to be minimized we have

$$
L(a,b,x,y,\lambda,\mu,\xi) = \pi a b + \lambda f(x,y) + \mu g(x,y)+ \xi \left(y-\frac{b^2}{b^2-a^2}\right)
$$

now considering instead the minimization of $S^2$ which in this case is equivalent to the minimization of $S$ we have

$$
L(a^2,b^2,x,y,\lambda,\mu,\xi) = \pi^2a^2b^2+\lambda\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1\right)+\mu\left(x^2+y^2-2y\right)+\xi\left(y- \frac{b^2}{b^2-a^2}\right)
$$

now making $\bar a = a^2, \bar b = b^2$

$$
L(\bar a,\bar b,x,y,\lambda,\mu,\xi) = \pi^2\bar a\bar b+\lambda\left(\frac{x^2}{\bar a}+\frac{y^2}{\bar b}-1\right)+\mu\left(x^2+y^2-2y\right)+\xi\left(y- \frac{\bar b}{\bar b-\bar a}\right)
$$

The stationary conditions give

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 -\frac{\lambda  x^2}{\bar a^2}+\bar b-\frac{\bar b \xi }{(\bar b-\bar a)^2}=0 \\
 -\frac{\lambda  y^2}{\bar b^2}+\bar a+\left(\frac{\bar b}{(\bar b-\bar a)^2}-\frac{1}{\bar b-\bar a}\right) \xi =0 \\
 \frac{2 \lambda  x}{\bar a}+2 \mu  x=0 \\
 \xi +\frac{2 \lambda  y}{\bar b}+\mu  (2 y-2)=0 \\
 \frac{x^2}{\bar a}+\frac{y^2}{\bar b}-1=0 \\
 x^2+y^2-2 y=0 \\
 y-\frac{\bar b}{\bar b-\bar a}=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and solving those equations we have the feasible solutions

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
\bar a & \bar b & x & y & \lambda& \mu & \xi & S^2\\
 \frac{3}{2} & \frac{9}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{27}{2} & -9 & 0 & \frac{27 \pi ^2}{4} \\
 \frac{3}{2} & \frac{9}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{27}{2} & -9 & 0 & \frac{27 \pi ^2}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

but $\bar a = a^2 \to a = \sqrt{\frac 32}, \bar b = b^2\to b = \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$